# Use dependencies downloaded during gradle clean during gradle bootRun

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, gradle, dockerfile

I am currently running a gradle project through Dockerfile. I require the build to be carried out on a development server which has internet connectivity and the docker image to be deployed on a production server which has no internet connectivity. For this purpose, I am trying to fetch all dependencies during gradle-clean. But when I run the docker image, it is again trying to download all the dependent jars from the repository. How can I make it point to the cache that is created during gradle-clean only.
I am new to the Docker framework, any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN mkdir -p /home/pma
WORKDIR /home/pma

VOLUME ["/home/pma"]
VOLUME ["/root/.gradle/caches/"]

#Setup gradle in the docker image and configure path variables
RUN \ 
    cd /usr/local && \
    curl -L https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-bin.zip -o gradle-4.2.1-bin.zip && \
    unzip gradle-4.2.1-bin.zip && \
    rm gradle-4.2.1-bin.zip
ENV GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/gradle-4.2.1
ENV PATH=$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

#Add the base code to the docker image
ADD . /home/pma/

#Here I am trying to download all dependencies which will be pushed to /root/.gradle/caches/
RUN ["gradle","--stacktrace","clean"]

#to be executed during the container creation phase
CMD ["gradle","--stacktrace","bootRun"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to build a complete docker image and bring it in production.

If you want to use cached dependencies only, use `--offline` when calling a gradle task.

Gradle is only resolving the dependencies of the configurations needed when executing a task, e.g. the `compile` dependencies won't be resolved without calling the compile task or another task based on the `compile` configuration and its dependencies.

You could write a custom task iterating through all configurations and resolving the dependencies.

Looks like somebody else had this problem before: [Gradle Task to Resolve All Configured Dependencies](https://jdpgrailsdev.github.io/blog/2014/10/28/gradle_resolve_all_dependencies.html)

This is what he was doing some years ago (I didn't test it myself):

```
task resolveDependencies {
    doLast {
        project.rootProject.allprojects.each { subProject ->
            subProject.buildscript.configurations.each { configuration ->
                configuration.resolve()
            }
            subProject.configurations.each { configuration ->
                configuration.resolve()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the --offline mode also for the gradle bootRun, but it throws error about not being able to resolve dependencies. It is still not looking for the dependencies in local, although it is downloading dependencies during gradle build. Is there some other way to access the gradle caches folder inside the docker image?